# What is the difference between maxActive vs. maxIdle for Tomcat connection pools?

Tags: tomcat, database-connection

The tomcat connection pool has a setting called maxActive and a setting called maxIdle my questions are.

1. What is the difference between these two settings?
2. What is a real world example scenario where you might have a different value for maxActive than you would for maxIdle?

For some reason the docs are not making sense to me. maxActive and maxIdle exist on both the apache dbcp and the tomact 7 jdbc-pool according to the docs at 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

> maxActive  (int) The maximum number of active connections that can be
>   allocated from this pool at the same time. The default value is 100
>
> maxIdle    (int) The maximum number of connections that should be kept
>   in the pool at all times. Default value is maxActive:100 Idle
>   connections are checked periodically (if enabled) and connections that
>   been idle for longer than minEvictableIdleTimeMillis will be released.
>   (also see testWhileIdle)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

maxActive is straight forward. maxIdle can be explained in this way - say you have 100 max Active connections and say you set maxIdle to 80. Assuming there are no requests going to the database, only 80 connections will be tested (via the validationquery) and will stay active. The other 20 will be closed. So at any point you can only have 80 idle connections.
You might want to set this to be a different number to prevent additional (unnecessary) connections going out to the database. Cos every connection that is served by the database consumes resources (like memory).
But, assuming you have set the maxActive size to 100 and all 100 are in use almost all the time, this setting will obviously not matter.

Comment: 1. what do u mean when you write 80 connections will be tested? why Another 20 is closed? I do not understand what benefit does maxActive have.

Comment: what happens when the number of required connections exceeds the maxActive value?

Comment: @BiGGZ Connection Pool will wait `maxWait` ms. If no connection is returned to  the poll during this time it will throw an exception.

Comment: @grep The idea of having maxActive and maxIdle is to allow the size of the pool to adapt to the load. While maxActive determines the  size of the pool when the load is high, maxIdle limits the size of the pool when the load is low - for performance benefits.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54085623/2506172 for detailed explanation

Comment: @BiGGZ as @(Mike Yakovets) mentioned, maxWait parameter governs the amount of the that the pool waits for a connection to be available. Post that, [PoolExhaustedException](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolExhaustedException.html) is thrown

Comment: Is there any negative effects if I set my maxActive to -1(no limit) and maxIdle to 100?

Comment: what is mean by maxIdle= -1?

Answer (score 17):

#### maxActive

```
the maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
```

This attribute is used to limit the number of connections a pool can have open.

#### maxIdle

```
(int) The maximum number of connections that should be kept in the pool **at all times.**
```

This is to limit the idle connections. The connections(not larger than the value of maxIdle) will not be released so that the next request for connections will be much faster.

So in a word, maxActive is to limit max connections.

But idle(`maxIdle` or `minIdle`) is more for performance issue(exchange time with space/resources) , among which, the maxIdle is to limit the max connections(the resources) that you are going to exchange time with.

Comment: Thank you and accepted answer for clarifying this moment! Now i have a bit knowledge how to tweak the pool.

Comment: Is there any negative effects if I set my maxActive to -1(no limit) and maxIdle to 100?

Comment: you may suffer from running out of resources when there are enough resource requests

Answer (score 17):

Let's say you have defined the property as

```
maxActive = 100
```

which essentially means

```
Size of the pool = maxActive = 100
```

**Problem with having just *maxActive***

```
Size of pool under heavy load = maxActive
Size of pool under no/low load = maxActive
```

Even when there is no load(`none of the connections are actually in use`), all 100 connections are consuming resources

You definitely can reduce *maxActive* to say 80. But doing that will also mean that you are lowering the upper bound of available connections during heavy load(`when application is consuming all available connections`) as well to 80.

Thus, you are stuck with *maxActive* as the size of the pool

**How *maxIdle* solves the above problem**

Let's say you have defined the properties as

```
maxActive = 100
maxIdle = 80
```

which essentially means

```
Size of pool under heavy load = maxActive = 100
Size of pool under low load = maxIdle = 80
```

*maxIdle* gives the connection pool the flexibility to adapt to load.
During high load (`number of connections-in use > maxIdle`), *maxActive* is the only property that determines the size of the connection-pool

But during no load(`number of connections in-use < than maxIdle`), *maxIdle* determines the size of the connection-pool

So a correct value of maxIdle ensures that connection pooling doesn't have unnecessary performance implications.

Comment: Is there any negative effects if I set my maxActive to -1(no limit) and maxIdle to 100?

Comment: @user10098815 that would simply mean that you will have no more than 100 idle connections in the pool if the number of connections-in-use is less than 100.

Answer (score 5):

In small enviroments, connections to databases are not a problem, because there aren't so much connections, and server resources are almost intact. In big enviroments, the number of connections to database consume a lot of resources, so, you need to optimize the manner you manage database connections, using the less possible number of connections will give you a better performance. In this point, maxActive set the max number of connections that can be made to the database by that pool, limiting the resources assigned to the requester. With maxIdle you specify that, if a connection "is idle" it will be closed, unless there are min "maxIdle" connections. Why not less than maxIdle?, because you need some connections tobe ready for next requests to the database, so you don't need to open and close again so many connections if the pool must be filled, so, you free a lot of resources.