# Using Tomcat server to host android and web application opens too many connections

Tags: android, spring, tomcat, servlets

I have an Web application running on my Tomcat server v7.0. Now I'm creating an android app and it will connect to MySQL database. For this, I'm going to send requests to this server, and this server will get data from database to Android app.

Now, I'd like you to think on the situation: if I have 1000 users connected to my webPage and more 1000 users getting data from MySQL database (as I said, the server will be in the middle of the communication between MySQL and Android), will my Tomcat server open 2000 connections?
I'm know it's difficult to the server receives such number of connections at the same time, but what I'm wondering is: will Tomcat server closes connections once the request is done?

I don't know if it is useful to answer this question, but I'm using spring MVC framework in the web application and Android spring in the Android application.

Answer (score 0):

That is what JDBC connection pools are for. Take a look at the documentation on [how to configure them](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)

Comment: I'll take a look at it, but does it keep connections opened once the request is done?

Comment: Connections are returned to the pool once the application code is done with them. It is the pool's job to scale the number of open connections based on requirement. The number of active and open connections are managed by the maxActive and maxIdle properties. This is discussed here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451818/what-is-the-difference-between-maxactive-vs-maxidle-for-tomcat-connection-pools